# How to get the Combo Box Value

Tags: python, combobox, tkinter, ttk

Hi everyone this is my first post here, i have been reading the questions relating to this topic but nothing seems to work at the moment so here is my question. I created a small app to store data relating to the work i do. how ever the combo box is not returning the value using the get() any suggesting based on the code below?`

```
update_news_combo = None


news = ['Mid Day News','Evening News']
features = ['Calling Farmers','Round About Ja','You and the Law','Get the Facts','Career Talk', 'Economy and you','Arts Page',
                    'Tourism Roundup','Jeep','Jamaica Promise','House Matters','Jamaica House Weekly','Urbanscope','Sports Spotlight',
                    'Share the love','Saturday News','Sunday News','Healthline','Open Feature']
features.sort()


class MenuCommands(object):
    def about_popup(self):
        messagebox.showinfo(title = "About Feature Tracker", message = 'This app is used to track Features and news edited')
    def update_popup(self):
        messagebox.showinfo(title = "File Update", message = "%s  has been Added"%update_news_combo.get())
root = Tk()
root.title('Feature Tracking')
root.geometry('255x425')
updateframe = ttk.Frame(root,padding = (5,10))          

popup = MenuCommands()

#Update Menu Frame
updateframe = ttk.Frame(root,padding = (5,10))
ttk.Label(updateframe,text ='Select Feature to add').grid(row = 0,column = 0)
update_feature_combo = ttk.Combobox(updateframe,values=features)
update_feature_combo.bind("<<>ComboboxSelected>")
update_feature_combo.grid(row = 1,column = 0)
ttk.Button(updateframe,text ='Add').grid(row = 2, column = 0)
ttk.Label(updateframe,text ='Select News to add').grid(row = 3,column = 0)
update_news_combo = ttk.Combobox(updateframe,values=news)
update_news_combo.bind("<<>ComboboxSelected>")
update_news_combo.grid(row = 4, column = 0)
news_label = ttk.Label(updateframe,textvariable = update_news_combo.get())
news_label.grid(row = 6,column = 0)
add_news =ttk.Button(updateframe,text ='Add',command = popup.update_popup)
add_news.grid(row = 5, column = 0)







def show_view_frame():
        viewframe.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        updateframe.grid_forget()

def show_update_frame():
        updateframe.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        viewframe.grid_forget()


#Menu bar with menu options
menubar = Menu(root)

#Update Menu
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
filemenu.add_command(label = 'New',command =show_update_frame)
filemenu.add_command(label = 'View',command =show_view_frame)
menubar.add_cascade(label = 'Update',menu = filemenu)




root.mainloop()
```

`
Thanks in advance for your suggestions and help.

Comment: Welcome Stack Overflow. Could you please reduce your code to a minimal version that showcases the issue?

Comment: i made some edits was that enough or i need to take more out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simplified your code and made a working example but you should consider learning Python a bit more before dealing with complex GUI.

```
from tkinter import messagebox, Tk, Menu, ttk

news = ['Mid Day News', 'Evening News']
features = ['Calling Farmers', 'Round About Ja', 'You and the Law', 'Get the Facts',
            'Career Talk', 'Economy and you', 'Arts Page', 'Tourism Roundup',
            'Jeep','Jamaica Promise', 'House Matters', 'Jamaica House Weekly']
features.sort()

class CustomMenu(object):
    def __init__(self, root, values=[], combo_placement=(0, 0), button_placement=(0, 0), label_placement=(0, 0)):
        self.frame = root
        self.combobox = ttk.Combobox(self.frame, values=values)
        self.combobox.bind("<<>ComboboxSelected>")
        self.combobox.grid(row=combo_placement[0], column=combo_placement[1])
        self.label = ttk.Label(self.frame, textvariable=self.combobox.get())
        self.label.grid(row=label_placement[0], column=label_placement[1])
        self.button = ttk.Button(self.frame, text="Add", command=self.update_popup)
        self.button.grid(row=button_placement[0], column=button_placement[1])

    def update_popup(self):
        messagebox.showinfo(
            title="File update",
            message="{} has been added".format(self.combobox.get())
        )


root = Tk()
root.title('Feature Tracking')
root.geometry('255x425')

update_frame = ttk.Frame(root, padding=(5,10))
def show_update_frame():
    update_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

#Update Menu Frame
features_frame = CustomMenu(update_frame, features, (1, 0), (3, 0), (0, 0))
news_frame = CustomMenu(update_frame, news, (4, 0), (5, 0), (6, 0))

#Menu bar with menu options
menubar = Menu(root)

#Update Menu
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
filemenu.add_command(label='New', command=show_update_frame)
menubar.add_cascade(label='Update', menu=filemenu)

root.config(menu = menubar)

root.mainloop()
```

What that shows is that you should not use global if you can do without them. The class I made is pretty ugly but at least each of the "CustomMenu" can reference to its own combobox to fetch the selected value.

Comment: Thank you for all your help Volent, it worked and solved my problem. I also see what you did, you created the objects and place them before you used them so you wont have trouble accessing them.

Answer (score 4):

this is a snippet of code that shows you how to use ttk Combobox widget:

```
def foo(event):#function called when '<<ComboboxSelected>>' event is triggered
    print v.get()#how to access to combobox selected item


root = Tk()
v = StringVar()#a string variable to hold user selection
options=["option 1", "option 2", "option 3"] #available combobox options
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
combo = Combobox(root,textvariable=v, values=options)
combo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',foo)#binding of user selection with a custom callback
combo.current(1)#set as default "option 2"
combo.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox


root = Tk()

root.geometry("400x400")
#^ Length and width window :D


cmb = ttk.Combobox(root, width="10", values=("prova","ciao","come","stai"))
#^to create checkbox
#^cmb = Combobox


#now we create simple function to check what user select value from checkbox

def checkcmbo():

if cmb.get() == "prova":
     messagebox.showinfo("What user choose", "you choose prova")

#^if user select prova show this message 
elif cmb.get() == "ciao":
    messagebox.showinfo("What user choose", "you choose ciao")

 #^if user select ciao show this message 
elif cmb.get() == "come":
    messagebox.showinfo("What user choose", "you choose come")

elif cmb.get() == "stai":
    messagebox.showinfo("What user choose", "you choose stai")

elif cmb.get() == "":
    messagebox.showinfo("nothing to show!", "you have to be choose something")




cmb.place(relx="0.1",rely="0.1")

btn = ttk.Button(root, text="Get Value",command=checkcmbo)
btn.place(relx="0.5",rely="0.1")

root.mainloop()
```